# how can I find gameobjects on the scene which owners is not me?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, photon

The method `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("name")` is only searches current player(owner)'s objects, but I need all gameobjects with one tag no matter whose those gameobjects.
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Can you provide enough information to have a [mcve]? Are your missing objects maybe **inactive** at that moment? [`GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) only finds **active** objects. As this API is in no way related to photon the owner doesn't matter at all ...

Comment: Do you mean visible? 
Yes, they’re all active gameobjects.

Answer (score 1):

Actually [GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("name")](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) should search the whole scene for the Tag, are you sure those objects in question have the tags assigned to them?

Comment: Yes, all objects I need have tags

Comment: @Minzhur are they maybe **inactive** at that moment? o.O

Answer (score 0):

Actually the reason that I couldn’t find all gameobjects is I checked objects before the other player’s objects appearing on my scene (the checking method was in method Start(), so I need to put the checking method in method Update(). Lol)

Comment: Hi Minzhur, if this problem is resolved you can mark one of these replies as the solution to close the thread, Thanks.